# MagicMock not called for signal handler in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, mocking, magicmock

I was in the middle of migrating some code and associated tests from python 2 to python 3 (specifically 2.7 to 3.7) and I came across this weird behavior that I'd like to understand:

```
try:
    from unittest import mock  # python 3
except ImportError:
    import mock  # python 2
import os
import signal


def do_signal(mock_type):
    def side_effect(signum, frame):
        print('Called for ' + mock_type.__name__)
    handler = mock_type(side_effect=side_effect)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)
    print(handler.call_count)


do_signal(mock.Mock)
do_signal(mock.MagicMock)
```

Here I use a `mock.Mock` or `mock.MagicMock` as a signal handler, and I print out the number of times the mock was called after sending the signal to the current process.

In python 2.7 this prints out:

```
Called for Mock
1
Called for MagicMock
1
```

But for python3.7 it prints out:

```
Called for Mock
1
0
```

For python 3 the MagicMock doesn't seem to be called at all. Reversing the order of the `do_signal` calls doesn't change this.

What behavior differences between `Mock` and `MagicMock` could explain this, and why would the behavior change from python 2 to 3? I know that `mock` was added to the standard library in python 3 as `unittest.mock`, so I'm curious whether something changed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in python 3, enumerations were added for signals

for example, you can call:

```py
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
```

and the first thing `signal.signal` attempts to do is convert the handle to an integer from an enum by calling `int(...)`

since `MagicMock` supports all of the magic methods, it also supports `__int__`

you can see this if you peek at the magic method calls:

```py
    # ...
    try:
        print(handler.__int__.call_count)
    except AttributeError:
        print('__int__ not called')
```

since the MagicMock has `__int__` :

```
>>> mock.MagicMock().__int__()
1
```

that reassigns the `SIGTERM` handler to signal 1 (`SIGHUP` on my platform)

Comment: Wow, I never thought to check for something like that. Thanks! And thanks for looking at my old questions :)